# how to add javascript variable value in facebook feed text

Tags: javascript

I m trying to add javascript variable value to facebook feed text function as below

```
var question = document.getElementById("question").value;

var attachment = {
    'name':'xyz',
    'href':'xyz',
    'caption':'testing',
    'description':  question ,
    'media':[{'type':'image','src':'9090.gif','href':'xyz.php'}]
    };
Facebook.streamPublish('', attachment);
```

but it is not displaying value of variable in that.
Please help me.....

Comment: What exactly is not shown? The value of `question`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Facebook (FBJS), you should use `getValue()` instead:

```
var question = document.getElementById("question").getValue();
```